# List of all Word addins through the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-word

I'm trying to get a complete overview of the addins associated with a Word installation using the command line. The idea is to run a script at all the users.

At this point I check the following location for startup elements, and the registry edit both for all users and for the specific user.

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins /s
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins /s
dir /s C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\STARTUP
```

Are there any other locations in either registry or on disk Word could keep addins information?

The data I want to get through the CLI is the same data is presented by this view in Word addins

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The tool Officeins by NirSoft found all the plugins for all Office programs
[OfficeIns](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/officeins.html).

Calling officeins from the command line with the '/sxml ' arguments prints a XML-structure with all the addins to desired location.

The program can also be run without installation.